# Is there a way to change the font in a python terminal to comic sans? edit: in replit

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts

I would like to change the font in my terminal based python program to comic sans because it is the greatest font ever.

edit: also probably should have specified that I am using replit because I am on chromebook at the moment. I would have asked on the replit forms but it is really inactive and has a lot of narcissists.

While I didn't get an answer for my specific situation I did figure out that in replit you can't change the font.

Comment: Python itself doesn't deal with fonts. How you do this will depend on where you are running the code. And it doesn't really have anything to do with programming. You might have better luck on [su] (though make sure to search for existing questions first, because this has probably already been answered).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Python shell. Open the start menu from start menu or double clicking the shortcut.
2. Click on the options from the top menu bar, and then click on Configure IDLE.
3. Change font size. Now in the fonts/tabs tab there will be option to change the font type/name and below it font size.

The above is if you are using python shell.
More info on this website: [wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Font-Size-in-Python-Shell)

Comment: What is "the Apple icon"? This question doesn't mention macOS or any particular terminal. What do you mean by "the Python shell"? IDLE? IDLE doesn't have a "Python" menu.

Comment: sry wrong thing, will fix

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

```py
import os
os.console.font = 'Comic Sans'
```